# Add background image to the bottom of div

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML / CSS code:

```html
<div class="tip">
    Some tip text
</div>
```

```css
div.tip {
   background: green url("green-tip.png") no-repeat center bottom / 100% auto;
   border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Basically I need to replicate the design:

[image]

The `green-tip.png` is just the pointer in the bottom:

[image]

However I get only a rectangle with round corners without the pointer in the bottom.

How to do this?

Comment: An easy solution is just have an additional div at the bottom of the tooltip that has the tip as its background.

Answer (score 3):

Use multiple background layer:

```css
div.tip {
  --h: 50px; /* height of the bottom part */

  border-radius: 18px 18px 0 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 222px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(rgb(42 157 143) 0 0)
    top / 100% calc(100% - var(--h)) no-repeat,
   url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN0S5.png") 
    bottom / 101% var(--h) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="tip">
  Some tip text
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this would be to add another div at the bottom:

```css
div.tip {
  background: rgb(42, 157, 143);
  border-radius: 18px 18px 0 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 222px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.bottom {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN0S5.png") no-repeat center bottom / 100% auto;
  height: 42px;
  width: 223px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tip">
    Some tip text
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way, using `::after` pseudoelement (useful if you want to use it in several places on your site):

```css
div.tip {
  background: rgb(42, 157, 143);
  border-radius: 18px 18px 0 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 222px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container::after {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN0S5.png") no-repeat center bottom / 100% auto;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 42px;
  width: 223px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tip">
    Some tip text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One suggestion to use `min-height` on `div.tip` in case content grows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to be part of the background as well, a simple (not necessarily most extendable) way of doing this would be to set both as background divs and place them in vertical block together

**CSS**

Here's your rectangle style class:

```
.rounded-top-rectangle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here's your image style class:

```
.image-below {
    display: block;
    width: 100px; /* Adjust this to control the size of the image */
    height: auto; 
    background-image: url('green-tip.png'); /* or similar */
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="rounded-top-rectangle"></div>
<div class="image-below"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can write like this

```
<body>
    <div class="tip">
      <p>Some tip text</p>
    </div>
  </body>
  <style>
    div.tip {
      background-image: url("green-tip.png");
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: flex;
      padding-left: 20px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: left;
    }
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Even your example image which was written by you shows the wrong layout of what the OP originally was asking about. Why did you post this answer here, what are you answering?